# Limit of mappings over a real function F

Tags: functions

I have read in a book that if we let $F$ be a bounded function, and $M$ a mapping, such that $F = MF$ is satisfied.
Then
$$F = \lim_{N \to \infty}M^NF$$
is valid.

Can this be the case in general?

To clarify as has been asked, does this stand true for any $F$ (not necessarily a real valued function or a bounded one) with any mapping $M$, where the condition $F = MF$ is still held?

Comment: As far as I know, "mapping" and "function" are synonymous, so why here one is function and the other mapping?

Comment: @Timbuc: In more recent times, one calls "function" a map that takes number values. This is unlike "pure" and "classical" set theory where this distinction does not show up. I do not know the reason of this. It is like in functional analysis when we talk about "functionals", even though they are functions.

Comment: @AlexM. Thanks....but then what is "mapping" here?

Comment: @Timbuc: "Mapping" is what you probably would call "function". To summarize: if $X$ and $Y$ are sets, then $f:X \mapsto Y$ is a "map"; if $Y \subset \mathbb C$, then $f$ is a "function".

Comment: @Alex Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it is satisfied, but in a trivial and not very interesting way. If $F=MF$ then, by induction, $F=M^N F \space \forall N \geq 0$ and then immediately $F=\lim \limits _{N \to \infty} M^N F$ (the limit being pointwise).

Let me add that the assumption of the boundedness of $F$ is totally irrelevant.

Comment: I don't understand the induction here, and apparently $\;FM\;$ is some kind of multiplication but *not* composition...?

Comment: @Timbuc: It is true that the OP has been sloppy in formulating his question. How I understand it: let $\mathcal F$ be some space of functions and let $M : \mathcal F \mapsto \mathcal F$ be a map such that $M(F)=F$ for a certain $F$, not necessarily unique (i.e. $M(F)(x)=F(x) \space \forall x$). (In other words, $F$ is a fixed point for $M$.) The rest now follows naturally.

Comment: Thanks, I see...but then the question is completely trivial: it says that if some set (of function)  is mapped to itself under some map, then that set (function) is mapped to itself by any power (i.e., composition, I guess) of the map with itself...

Comment: @Timbuc: I myself have noted this triviality in my answer. This is why I think that the question is quite shallow.

Comment: Yes, my question is trivial and quite obvious - I hated asking it. But the word pointwise was what explained what I initially wanted to know.

Answer (score 1):

The question you're asking has ties to the theory of dynamical systems, where you take some map $M$, iterate it, and see what happens. Situations like this can be very complicated; see, for instance, the [Mandelbrot set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandelbrot_set). In particular, there is no reason to expect that an iterate should converge. For instance, take $M:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ to be the function $M(x)=x+1$. Then
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} M^nF(x) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \big(n + F(x)\big) = \infty.
$$

Comment: The OP assumes that $MF=F$, which seems not to be the case in your example.

Comment: I see what you mean. I interpreted "Can this be the case in general?" to mean "What happens if $MF\neq F$", but now I see that the question is inherently vague. It's a question of which hypothesis you relax.

Comment: Only now, after reading your comment, do I realize that maybe your interpretation is correct and mine wrong. It is probably the OP's duty to step in and clarify his question.

Comment: @Alex M, I updated.